# In flutter i want to download pdf file but it shows me error

Tags: flutter, pdf

in flutter i upload a pdf file from admin account when i try to download it from client side it shows
I/System.out(20826): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out(20826): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
on screen it shows failed to download the pdf. help me solve it

i want to download the pdf on client side

Comment: Add some code please so we can figure out issue